# /etc/rc.local (run via systemd) hangs when cat'ing /dev/urandom

Tags: scripts, startup, systemd

I created an `/etc/rc.local`:

```
$ cat /etc/rc.local 
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting"
randomString=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1`
echo "Finished"
```

This runs when run interactively:

```
$ /etc/rc.local 
Starting
Finished: lkFcvByNaIu7zmxuCYB3BQmJ05LwuVWL
```

However, when run from systemd it hangs and doesn't return.

If I ctrl+C it looks like it is hanging at the `fold` command:

```
$ systemctl status rc-local
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabl
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─debian.conf
   Active: activating (start) since Mon 2019-03-11 12:04:06 UTC; 12s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-rc-local-generator(8)
Cntrl PID: 936 (rc.local)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rc-local.service
           ├─936 /bin/bash /etc/rc.local start
           ├─952 /bin/bash /etc/rc.local start
           ├─953 cat /dev/urandom
           ├─954 tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9
           └─955 fold -w 32

Mar 11 12:04:06 ip-10-0-4-116 systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Mar 11 12:04:06 ip-10-0-4-116 rc.local[936]: Starting
```

```
$ ps -ef
root       936     1  0 12:04 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /etc/rc.local start
root       952   936  0 12:04 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /etc/rc.local start
root       953   952 47 12:04 ?        00:00:23 cat /dev/urandom
root       954   952 36 12:04 ?        00:00:18 tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9
root       955   952 10 12:04 ?        00:00:05 fold -w 32
```

#### Workaround (of sorts)

I didn't really need a *very* random string, so instead I could use:

```
date | md5sum | cut -c -12
```

To generate a string. This works fine when run by systemd. But it would be interesting to know why the previous command would hang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dan!

IMHO, **cat /dev/urandom** is bound to last forever, so you should use a command to read just first i.e. eighty lines of random content and then close input.

Using simple **head -80** you still have surplus characters which you don't use, but it should not stall forever, as it is closing **/dev/urandom** after 80 linefeeds (or CRLFs). This is an ugly hack:

```
$ cat /etc/rc.local 
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting"
randomString=`head -80 /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1`
echo "Finished"
```

Behavior in the background task is different IMHO because systemd doesn't know when will cat **/dev/urandom** finish reading from the random number device. It seems the same, but obviously, it isn't. Your script depends on breaking pipes once the last head command finishes, so it is not reliable to be portable. It can also the end with "Broken Pipe" signal which previous command in the pipeline have caught and processed. In init script ran by systemd there may not be provision for such communication and **cat /dev/urandom** hangs as it doesn't receive **SIGPIPE** signal or something ...

Hope this helps.

This doesn't guarantee 32 characters in the range **[A-Za-z0-9]**, but the emphasis is on closing **/dev/urandom** instead of relying on **SIGPIPE** magic to terminate the process, which appears not working properly in the background, without a control terminal.

You can also do:

```
randomString=`head -80 /dev/urandom | md5sum | cut -c -12`
```

as in your second example. It is as random as `/dev/urandom` gives.

Comment: _Dan!_ not sure if Alan Partridge reference or...

Comment: Look I don't know who you are or why my dead ancestors sent you and askubuntu to save me from jumping off a cliff but thank you for solving a 6 hour problem for me. "I'll just generate a random hostname and save it from an systemd startup task" I said 6 hours ago.  I'm sure this comment violates the rules or something but I don't care.  Thank you!